# convert an alphanumeric string into a numeric one

Tags: python, string

I looked around and I do not see a clear answer for Python to convert an alphanumeric string to a numeric one.  Here is an example of numbers I would like to convert.

```
"1234alpha" --> 1234
"a1234asdf" --> 0
"1234.56yt" --> 1234.56
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

DK

Comment: Why is `"a1234asdf" --> 0` ?

Comment: Are you looking to convert the initial numeric prefix, and ignore everything that comes after, like C's `atoi` function?

Comment: Because numbers imbedded in strings are clearly meant to be a part of the string.  Whereas leading numbers may be something like 1234*t and I just want the leading p[art

Comment: Yes, @Abamert something like VFP...

Comment: That's kind of an odd assumption… but if that's your intention, this is a dup of [Python equivalent to atoi / atof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665511/python-equivalent-to-atoi-atof).

Comment: What's VFP? You don't mean ARM-style Virtual Floating Point or Vector Ploating Point, and I can't think of anything else programming-related off the top of my head…

Comment: No, Visual FoxPro, the ultimate language for humans, @Abanert!

Comment: @user2460897: I wasn't aware that the ultimate language for humans had words like `ENDIF` and `ENDFOR`, required you to shout all syntactic words, or pronounced "true" as `dot T dot`…

Comment: You may feel resentment for these little things, but if you want to be productive, VFP represents 5 high level languages in one!  And they are all tightly integrated.  C# is MS's attempt to send VFP into the Dark Ages and it failed miserably.  VFP rocks!

Comment: Is it OK if `1234` is returned as `1234.0`? Or if `1234.0` is returned as `1234`?

Answer (score 4):

For a change `itertools` and no regex:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> number = ''.join(it.takewhile(str.isdigit, '123dfd'))
>>> int(number) if number else 0
123
>>> number = ''.join(it.takewhile(str.isdigit, 'a123dfd'))
int(number) if number else 0
0
```

Somewhat uglier it works for floats:

```
>>> number = ''.join(it.takewhile(lambda x: x.isdigit() or 
                                   x == '.', '123.45dfd'))
>>> float(number) if number else 0
123.45
```

Floats, negatives:

```
def make_number(alphanum):
    sign = 1
    if alphanum and alphanum[0] in '+-':
        sign = int(alphanum[0] + '1')
        alphanum = alphanum[1:]
    try:    
        return float(''.join(it.takewhile(lambda x: x.isdigit() 
                                           or x == '.', alphanum))) * sign
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

**Conclusion:** Changing the requirements along the way can turn a simple solution into a complicated one.

Comment: I like it, but you may want to do something about negitives

Comment: This is pretty much the OP's code in [the question that this is a dup of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665511/python-equivalent-to-atoi-atof). Except that his code handles negative numbers (and positive numbers with the legal but unnecessary `+` prefix), does the right thing on various errors, etc.

Comment: *clearly* this is the way to do it :)

Comment: +1 for avoiding regex when they are not necessary.

Comment: @Mike Müller your solution works for both examples, but it fails in the following case "1234.98ABC"

Comment: Any chance we can modify it to allow the inclusion of numbers beyond the decimal?

Comment: We're getting a bit silly... but bugs out with 12.34.56 or similar.

Comment: Not as nice, but works for floats and negatives too.

Answer (score 1):

To support positive/negative integer/float numbers, you could use a slightly modified regexp from [Extract float/double value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/python-and-regex-question-extract-float-double-value):

```
import re

re_float = re.compile("""(?x)
   ^
      [+-]?\ *      # first, match an optional sign *and space*
      (             # then match integers or f.p. mantissas:
          \d+       # start out with a ...
          (
              \.\d* # mantissa of the form a.b or a.
          )?        # ? takes care of integers of the form a
         |\.\d+     # mantissa of the form .b
      )
      ([eE][+-]?\d+)?  # finally, optionally match an exponent
   """)

def extract_number(s, default=None):
    m = re_float.match(s)
    if not m:
        return default # no number found
    f = float(m.group(0)) #XXX to support huge numbers, try/except int() first
    return int(f) if f.is_integer() else f
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/ysBQgH)

```
for s in sys.stdin:
    print(extract_number(s, default=0))
```

#### Input

```
1234alpha
a1234asdf
1234.56yt
-1e20.
```

#### Output

```
1234
0
1234.56
-100000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the re module:

```
import re

def alp(s):
    m = re.match('\d+', s)
    return int(m.group(0)) if m is not None and m.start() == 0 else 0

In [3]: alp('a1234asdf')
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: alp('1234alpha')
Out[4]: 1234
```

If you want to include negative integers:

```
def alp_neg(s):
    m = re.match('[+-]?\d+', s)
    return int(m.group(0)) if m is not None and m.start() == 0 else 0
```

If you want floats too:

```
def alp_floats(s):
    m = re.match('[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', s)
    return float(m.group(0)) if m is not None and m.start() == 0 else 0

In [7]: alp_floats('-12.2ss31.232sadas')
Out[7]: -12.2
```

Comment: First, this returns a string instead of an integer. Second, try it with `m = re.match('\d+', '-123dd1')`.

Comment: @abarnert that's a good point, I hadn't considered -

Comment: It works on the first example, buty on the second one it fails with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'"

Comment: @user2460897 can you try it again, I edited my answer part way through

Comment: @user2460897 also added floats

Comment: `alp_floats('+123.4abc')` returns  `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def str_to_int(string):
    match = re.match("\d+", string)
    if match:
        try:            
        return int(match.group())
    except ValueError:
        return float(match.group())
    else:
        return 0

str_to_int("1234alpha") 
1234
str_to_int("a1234asdf") 
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
from itertools import takewhile

ast.literal_eval(''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x<='9', string)) or '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

When the rules for what is OK become hard to define, you might consider this binary search approach that tries to find the bound.

```
def binsearch_prefix(seq, predicate):
    best_upper = 0
    lower, upper = 0, len(seq)
    while lower < upper:
        mid = (lower + upper) / 2
        if predicate(seq[:mid]):
            best_upper = mid
            lower = mid + 1
        else:
            upper = mid
    return seq[:best_upper]
```

It will return the part of the string that you consider acceptable. For example, this could be your accept function:

```
def can_float(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Example:

```
print binsearch_prefix(can_float, "1234alpha") # "1234"
print binsearch_prefix(can_float, "a1234asdf") # ""
print binsearch_prefix(can_float, "1234.56yt") # "1234.56"
```

You may then format the prefix any way you like.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use regular expressions?

```
import re

def str2num(s):
    try:
        num = re.match(r'^([0-9]+)', s).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        num = 0
    return int(num)

print str2num('1234alpha')
print str2num('a1234asdf')
```

Output:

```
1234
0
```

Comment: This raises an exception for the OP's test case `'a1234asdf'` instead of returning 0. It also does the wrong thing in all kinds of other cases.

Comment: @dblslash, you are closer because yours returns a numeric value, but it fails with the second example!  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @dblslash, you are correct, that works fine now, though a little lengthy, but worthy.  Any chance we can include numbers beyond the decimal point?

Comment: Yeah, if you use `r'^([0-9\.]+)'` as your regular expression, and then cast to a `float` instead of in `int`.