# Range for numbers 1 to 3

Tags: python

I'm trying to complete a school project where I create a maths quiz that randomly generates questions. You have to login with a name and classroom your in.
All my code works apart from the section of code where I am trying to use a range for my class (Between class 1 and 3). It keeps popping up with an error saying:

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

```
while True:
  classCode=input("What class are you in? 1, 2, or 3? ")
  if 1 <= classCode <= 3:
    break
  else:
    print("That isn't a class. Please try again.")
    continue
```

Anyone know whats wrong with this code?
This is my first question so if it's not in the right format I apologize.

Comment: So the error message is clear, what type do you think `classCode` is? You need to cast it to an int `int(classCode)`

Comment: as an aside, you could write `if classCode in list(range(1, 4)):` or `if classCode in [1, 2, 3]:`

Comment: @WilliamPerron Things like `2 in range(1, 4)` work, the `list()` wrapper isn't required. But since the range is so small I'd use a literal tuple here. FWIW, the interpreter will actually convert a literal list like `[1, 2, 3]` into a tuple.

Comment: `classCode` is a `string`, and you need to convert it to an int. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665511/python-equivalent-to-atoi-atof) on how to convert it to an `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` retrieves a string input from the user. You need to cast it to an int type.
Something like:

```
classCodeStr=input("What class are you in? 1, 2, or 3? ")
classCode = int(classCodeStr)
```